# Increment Multiple Timestamp Values with PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I don't know Oracle at all, but I need to write something like this:

MySQL:

```
  SET @serial:=1;  
  UPDATE table1 SET t = t + INTERVAL (@serial:=@serial+1) SECOND;`
```

Update and increment a timestamp by one second for all records.  How to do this in Oracle?

**Question Update:** 
My wording was not explaining my problem well enough.

I want to have a variable of (TimeStamp).

Then go through all records incrementing this variable with one second every time for a record update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this as per my understanding

```
DECLARE
    serial number := 1;
BEGIN
    update table1 set t= t + (( serial + rownum - 1 )/86400);
END;
```

This will do increment like below

```
1st row -> 1 sec
2nd row -> 2 sec
.
.
nth row -> nsec
```

though the `serial` starts from 1

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be

```
update table1 set t= t + interval '1' second;
```

Read more about [Interval literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm)

---

As per your update, it should be

```
DECLARE
    t_update_time date := sysdate;  
BEGIN
    update table1 set t=t_update_time + interval '1' second;
END;
```

This snippet assigns current datetime to t_update_time variable, and updates the record with 1 second added to the datetime declared in t_update_time. Change t_update_time assignment accordingly.

---

Without a PL/SQL switch it should be as

```
update table1 set t=to_date('21.01.2015 09:00:00','dd.mm.rrrr hh:mi:ss') + interval '1' second;
```

Comment: Okay, just one problem. My fault I did not word it well enough. Irrespective of the time in the record, I want to update all records from one start time. I will edit the question above.

Comment: Please see the update, I think it's what you require.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple actually. Just do:

```
update table1 set t = t + 1/86400;
```

After question update, you can do:

```
DECLARE
    t_serial number;
    cursor c is select * from table1 for update of t;
    cr table1%rowtype;
BEGIN
    t_serial := 1;
    for cr in c loop
       UPDATE table1 SET t = t_serial/86400 WHERE CURRENT OF c;
       t_serial := t_serial + 1;
    end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Okay, just one problem. My fault I did not word it well enough. Irrespective of the time in the record, I want to update all records from one start time. I will edit the question above.